# Which partition do I need to format or fix in order to install Sierra or lion?

Tags: macos, partition, install, disk-format

I have tried in vain to get my MacBook Air back up and running. I did a system restore or reinstall a while back and something broke.

I've tried <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and a bootable USB, there doesn’t appear to be a time machine partition or option.

[image]

[image]

Which partition should I format? Can I clear them all and start from scratch?

If someone could show me how to get this issue resolved so I can use my laptop again that’d be great.

Comment: Have you tried using the Disk Utility to erase the internal drive? Do you know the model year of your Mac? Do you know the latest version of macOS that was installed? Do you have another Mac available? If so, what is the model/year and version of macOS?

Comment: I just bought a new MacBook Pro today with the M1, the other MacBook was a loner from work like 7 years ago. It was Yosemite I think but I reformatted and upgraded to Sierra years ago. It ran fine but was getting laggy and I attempted to reformat and tinker with disk partitions. Ideally I’d like to blow away the partitions entirely, create a new one with full size and install from a bootable USB on the single newly formatted partition. I’ve done this in windows countless times, how do I do it with Mac?!?

Comment: Can you explain how to arrived at the point posted in your question? What I see is Mountain Lion installation software installed on the internal drive. There is no partition where Mountain Lion can be installed. There are no USB flash drives plugged into the Mac. If this is correct, then you did you do this?

Comment: I managed to connect to the internet and do a restore, that’s where the mountain comes from but the original was Sierra or less. I tried deleting the partitions with the GUI tool, thinking I could recreate a partition for the whole drive and reinstall from a USB boot disk I created using a windows tool called TransMac or something. Now it seems the two partitions have been assigned the entire disk and a new one cannot be created? If I downsize the two and creat a new partition and format I hope I can reinstall there?!?

Comment: Note that /Dev/disk1 thru 7 are notated as "(disk image)" and not actual physical drives. Rather they are virtual disks (if I remember correctly, in RAM) and can be completely ignored.

Comment: I’ve read that too. I’m thinking Disk0 and Disk0s2 occupy almost 100% of the 256gb drive. Not sure if that’s what’s causing the issue? Can I shrink them both to 10gb a piece and use remaining space for a newly formatted partition to get Mac OSX installed?

Answer (score 0):

When restarting your Mac, you may hold Command (⌘)-R to enter your local recovery partition. From there, you should be able to erase and format your internal storage drive (e.g. Macintosh HD) using Disk Utility.

***Please note that erasing your drive will result in data loss.***

For macOS Sierra or OS X Mountain Lion, you should erase your drive using a [GUID Partition Map](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/partition-schemes-disk-utility-mac-dsku1c614201/20.0/mac/11.0) and [Mac OS Extended (Journaled)](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/file-system-formats-available-in-disk-utility-dsku19ed921c/20.0/mac/11.0). For complete steps to erase and format your drive, please refer to [How to erase your Intel-based Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496). After erasing your drive, you should proceed with [reinstalling macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).

If you've completed the above steps but the same issue occurs, then there may be something wrong with your local recovery partition. You'll want to try the following next steps to access *internet* recovery (this requires an internet connection):

1. On an Intel-based Mac, you can use Option-Command-R at startup to upgrade to the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac, [with some exceptions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).
2. On an Intel-based Mac that previously used macOS Sierra 10.12.4 or later, you can use Shift-Option-Command-R at startup to install the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available.

If the above still fails to resolve the issue, you may try [creating a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) using another Mac if necessary.

If any issues persist after completing all of the above steps, you may be experiencing a hardware issue. I'd recommend [contacting Apple support](https://support.apple.com/contact) for further assistance.

Comment: I’ve tried all those steps...unfortunately. It’s something to do with the partition format. I have created a bootable USB and was hoping to just blow a away system partitions and reinstall over a newly created, formatted partition. I’ve done this dozens of times for windows and Linux pc - the same cannot be done for a Mac?